# moduleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' (SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I am new to the python and flask. I am watching a you tube tutorial and i am stuck at 20:05 where he run the code "from app import db". I follow exactly the step he taught but yet I still face this problem.Below are the program I type and at the terminal there it shows the error.

The Program:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False) #This is to set the character the person input
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow) #This is to set the time

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The Program I type In Terminal:

```
from app import db
```

The Respond After Typing The Command At Terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Visual Studio Code Project\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

The You Tube Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1RJmh_OqeA&t=335s

[The Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq27O.png)

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

"flask" is used as a Python module in VSCode, we need to install it in the current Python environment: please use "`pip install flask`" (or "`pip3 install flask`") in the VSCode terminal.

In addition, the module "flask_sqlalchemy" also needs to be installed. (`pip install flask_sqlalchemy`)

[image]

For more information about the use of "flask" in VSCode, please refer to [Flask Tutorial in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask).

Update:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank You for answering my question, but before that i have already install the flask and flask sqlalchemy in my virtual environment. But I still encounter the error O.o

Comment: @JackJTR -Please use the command "_pip show flask_" in the VSCode terminal to check whether the module "flask" is installed in the Python environment you are using.

Comment: Yup, it did already installed in the virtual environment. 
Here is a screenshot i took after i type in the comment "pip show flask"
https://imgur.com/T616EgX

Comment: @JackJTR -When these conditions are met, does the code still display "No module named'flask' "? Have you tried to run it by clicking the run button?

Comment: Yup, it still display Nomodulename 'flask" error O.o

Comment: @JackJTR -Did you try to remove the spaces in the folder name (Visual Studio Code Project)? And please try to reload or restart VSCode and run the code in the newly opened VSCode terminal.

Comment: @JackJTR -How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.